# Posting image to server using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http

Hi I have few string values and an image which I need to post on server using Javascript.

Can anyone tell me how do I pass the image in form.

I will be generating the form at runtime using Javascript.

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: I think file upload is not possible using ajax.

Comment: is the image a file on your local machine ?

Comment: AJAX or iframe should do.

Comment: you want to browse the image from pc ?
or post img element ?

Comment: look I have that image stored somewhere in the local storage and I will read that image from localstorage and send it to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a  [link](http://tips.itliveweb.com/ajax/upload-image-using-iframe-javascript-ajax.html) how to do it.

Basically you should use iframe. You can create iframe on the fly , or put in invisible mode.

In you javascript , you need to put image in the iframe as explaing above in the link.

Comment: I want to post a form at runtime with images. I will read data from localstorage and put the data in the form and post it on server

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following version jQuery plugin:
https://gist.github.com/AndrewRevinsky/5856405

Usage:

```
fileInputs.uploadFile({                                                                                        
    url: url,                                                                                                   
    secureuri: true,                                                                                      
    dataType: 'JSON',                                                                                           
    data: params,                                                                                               
    success: function (response, status) {                                                                      

    },                                                                                                          
    error: function (response, status, e) {                                                                     
    }                                                                                                           
});
```

If something is not working for you with this plugin, you can easily google for 'Ajaxupload' or 'Ajax file upload'.